# How can I make webpack "skip" the image source compilation from Vue?

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I have an image attribute inside my Vuejs component:

```
<img src="./photos/image.png">
```

I want webpack to bundle the whole .js but not the image.

Then, when the HTML is run from my server:

- The vuejs script will be called
- The **img src="./photos/image.png"** element will be created
- The source will be read by the server and the image will appear.

Is there a way to do this?

I get an error with webpack since it tries to fetch the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the question was unclear.

I eventually solved it by having the image source inside the computed component of Vue.

Element inside vue:

```
<img :src="imagePath">
```

Computed property:

```
computed: {
    imagePath: function(){ return 'photos/image.png' }
}
```

This way webpack does not try to bundle it, since **imagePath** is only rendered by Vue at runtime.

Comment: A simpler way to use this workaround is to still use a bound attribute, but just put the URl in the atribute as a string:
`<img :src="'photos/image.png'">`

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use `url-loader` rather than `file-loader` / `raw-loader`.

Check out the bible here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/